# can't add when I click add button

Tags: javascript, php, html

Can someone help me with this, whenever I click add button it doesn't save into mysql. even I go to inspect element, there is no error that appear, it just no response.

```
<form action='' method='POST' id='form_client_log' enctype='application/x-www/form-urlencoded'>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal modal-primary">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Quick Event</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body" id= 'result'>
```

I try to hide all the input_text for to know if it's adding into mysql

```
</div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <?php //input_text('contact_person', 'Contact Person', false);?>&nbsp
                    <?php //input_text('company', 'Company', false);?><br><br>
                    <?php// input_text('email', 'Email', false);?>&nbsp
                    <?php //input_text('contact_no', 'Contact Number', false);?><br><br>
                    <!-- Date: <input type='date' name='continue_date' id='continue_date'><br><br>
                    Note: <textarea name='remarks' id='remarks' row='4' cols='100'></textarea>-->
                    <?php input_hidden(); ?>
                    <input type="text" id="contact_no" name="contact_no" placeholder="Insert Number"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn" name='add' id='add' title='Add'></button>
                    <button type="button" class='btn' name='delete' id='delete' title='Delete'></button>

                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

and this is the code for the javascript for adding..

```
var client_logUI = "";
var client_log = new BizObject("client_log", function(){
    client_log = new BizObjectUI(client_log);
});
//create BizObject also for every foreign table source


$(document).ready(function(){       
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 0);

    $("#date_rel").datepicker(pickerOpts);
    $("#date_rel").datepicker("setDate", "today");
    $("#date_rel_search").datepicker(pickerOpts);

    setup_button_events("client_log", client_log, client_logUI);
});

client_log.after_new = function (){
    $("#id").val(client_log.data['id']);
}

client_log.after_add = function(){
    show_save_result(this);
}   

client_log.after_update = function (){
    show_save_result(this);
}

client_log.after_delete = function ()
{
    show_save_result(this);
    reset_fields("form_client_log");
    $("#btn_search").click();
}

client_log.after_select = function ()
{
    client_logUI.edit();
    //display values from foreign table here
    $("#message").html("");
    $("#btn_update").show();
    $("#btn_delete").show();

}   

client_log.is_valid = function()
{
    var fields = new Array('id','contact_person','company','email','contact_no','remarks');
    var field_labels = new Array('Contact Person','Company','Email','Contact Number','Note');
    var valid = is_valid("form_client_log", fields, field_labels);
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: You haven't bound the "add" button to any action nor do you have any code that would do any SQL insertion. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @apokryfos this is the SQL insertion..

<?php
 session_start();
    require("./php/japp.php");
    require("./php/jlite.php");
    $conn = connect(CONN_STRING, USER, PASSWORD);
 $conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
 $conn->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

 $table = "client_log";

 $qupdate = build_insert($conn, $table);
 $params = set_params($conn, $table);

 //set custom field values here $params["key"] = value;
 echo save_data($conn, $qupdate, $params);
?>

Comment: What about the binding of the "Add" button? Something like `$("#add").on("click", function() { // Do a submit here or something });` . Point being, Add is not a submit button.